# Using ATI Flgrx drivers

Tags: 12.04, grub2, ati, nomodeset

after installing ubuntu 12.04 i had the problem that i had a black screen directly after rebooting. So i used the grub option "nomodeset" to get an screen. I installed the recommended flgrx drivers and disabled the nomodeset option. Still can't use my graphics card. Also the option "xforcevesa" does not solve my problem.

I would need 3D enabled because i need blender to work. I hope someone can help my to get my ATI Graphics Card running. I don't want to use windows :D

This is my hardware `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller

    (rev 02) 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI
    Express x16 Root Port (rev 02) 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller:
    Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev
    02) 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06) 00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host
    Controller (rev 05) 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5
    Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05) 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express
    Root Port 1 (rev 05) 00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5
    Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05) 00:1d.0
    USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2
    Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05) 00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel
    Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5) 00:1f.0 ISA bridge:
    Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller
    (rev 05) 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400
    Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) 00:1f.3 SMBus:
    Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev
    05) 00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5
    Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05) 01:00.0 VGA
    compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series] 01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300 Series]
    02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
    03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n
    Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01) 7f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel
    Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core
    Registers (rev 02) 7f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core
    Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
    7f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02) 7f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI
    Physical 0 (rev 02) 7f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core
    Processor Reserved (rev 02) 7f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation
    Core Processor Reserved (rev 02
```

Comment: How did you install the fglrx driver? after doing a search it seems to affect people with on-board intel graphics. Is there an option in your bios to disable the on-board graphics. My card is a Radeon HD 5430 series and works without issue but I don't have on-board intel.

Answer (score 0):

there is no solution, the ati 5400 is not supported, amd and intel haven t wrote good driver, i have the same notebook, you have too disable the ati card with acpi_call, and use the intel 3d 
see :
http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com.es/2010/07/using-acpicall-module-to-switch-onoff.html

and desactivate ati driver